# Python - Finding index of first non-empty item in a list

Tags: python, list

What would be the most efficient\elegant way in Python to find the index of the first non-empty item in a list?

For example, with

```
list_ = [None,[],None,[1,2],'StackOverflow',[]]
```

the correct non-empty index should be:

```
3
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
>>> lst = [None,[],None,[1,2],'StackOverflow',[]]
>>> next(i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j)
3
```

if you don't want to raise a `StopIteration` error, just provide default value to the `next` function:

```
>>> next((i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j == 2), 42)
42
```

P.S. don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows built-in.

Answer (score 6):

One relatively elegant way of doing it is:

```
map(bool, a).index(True)
```

(where "a" is your list... I'm avoiding the variable name "list" to avoid overriding the native "list" function)

Comment: that only works in python-2.x and anyway it builds the whole list of boolean values.

Comment: @SilentGhost - True.  I didn't realize that map had changed in python3.

Answer (score 2):

```
try:
    i = next(i for i,v in enumerate(list_) if v)
except StopIteration:
    # Handle...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
next(i for (i, x) in enumerate(L) if x)
```

Answer (score 1):

for python 3.x
@Joe Kington solution is

```
list(map(bool, list_)).index(True)
```

Also consider working with values instead of indexes

```
for value in filter(bool, list_):
    ...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31602857)

Answer (score 0):

```
next(i for i, v in enumerate(list) if v)
```