# Python - Finding index of first empty item in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to find the index of the first empty item from the following list:

```
list_ = [10000.0, 6000.0, nan, nan, nan]
```

and to show the correct output as an index of:

```
2
```

I have been referring to the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229626/python-finding-index-of-first-non-empty-item-in-a-list) but I keep receiving the "StopIteration:" error message. Does anyone have the solution to this?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
try:
    next(i for i, j in enumerate(list_) if j == "nan")
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `nan`?

Comment: Its datatype is numpy.float64. I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your check condition is wrong, it tries to find an item equal to **string** `"nan"`. To check if a float var is nan, use `math.isnan(j)`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This one is a little tricky, because `nan` is not equal to itself.

However, your current solution is easily adaptable using [`isnan`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.isnan):

```
import math

try:
    index = next(i for i, j in enumerate(list_) if math.isnan(j))
except StopIteration:
    # nan is not in the list 
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be a more pythonic way to do this, but this is what I would do:

```
from numpy import nan, isnan

list_ = [10000.0, 6000.0, nan, nan, nan]

for ind, elem in enumerate(list_):
    if isnan(elem):
        print ind
        break
```